# Getting the position and dimensions of a Polygon

Tags: kineticjs

I have a Kinetic.Polygon object on the stage with multiple points. I'm trying to calculate the dimensions of the polygon's bounds and the dimensions. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get this info by enumerating through the polygon's points and getting mins and maxes.**

```
var minX=minY=1000000;
var maxX=maxY=-1000000;

var points=myPolygon.getPoints();

for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    var p=points[i];
    if(p.x<minX){minX=p.x;}
    if(p.y<minY){minY=p.y;}
    if(p.x>maxX){maxX=p.x;}
    if(p.y>maxY){maxY=p.y;}
}

var width=maxX-minX;
var height=maxY-minY;

var boundsLeft=minX+myPolygon.getX();
var boundsRight=boundsLeft+width;
var boundsTop=minY+myPolygon.getY();
var boundsBottom=boundsTop+height;
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/FghXD/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 778,
        height: 600
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
        x:200,
        y:20,
        points: [73, 192, 73, 160, 340, 23, 500, 109, 499, 139, 342, 93],
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 5,
        draggable:true
      });

      poly.on("dragend",function(){
          calc();
      });

      function calc(){
          var minX=minY=1000000;
          var maxX=maxY=-1000000;

          var points=poly.getPoints();

          for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
              var p=points[i];
              if(p.x<minX){minX=p.x;}
              if(p.y<minY){minY=p.y;}
              if(p.x>maxX){maxX=p.x;}
              if(p.y>maxY){maxY=p.y;}
          }

          var width=maxX-minX;
          var height=maxY-minY;

          var boundsLeft=minX+poly.getX();
          var boundsRight=boundsLeft+width;
          var boundsTop=minY+poly.getY();
          var boundsBottom=boundsTop+height;

          alert("w/h: "+width+"/"+height+" -- bounds(t/l-b/r): "+boundsTop+"/"+boundsLeft+"-"+boundsBottom+"/"+boundsRight);
      }

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(poly);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```